# How to match a WiredTiger index file to its corresponding collection

Tags: mongodb, mongo-repair

I have a mongodb database with about 2 billion records, shared between 20 or so collections. Each of these collections has an index on it, based on a single key (other than _id).

I have an index file (named index-1-5374774422504609475.wt) that I'd like to match to a collection. Is there a quick way to match directly which index file corresponds to a collection?

I do mean the actual physical index file in the mongo db directory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ref:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/#collStats.indexDetails

As you are using WiredTiger storage engine you can use `db.collection.stats()` with `indexDetails` option set to `true`.

Easy copy paste:

`.stats({"indexDetails":true})`

> A document that reports data from the WiredTiger storage engine for
>   each index in the collection. Other storage engines will return an
>   empty document.
>
> The fields in this document are the names of the indexes, while the
>   values themselves are documents that contain statistics for the index
>   provided by the storage engine. These statistics are for internal
>   diagnostic use.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Should've RTFM, thanks!